# Save Excel file to Confluence File List via Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, confluence

I am trying to create a macro that updates three workbooks from a single data source (ticket system data for my team).

I've got the macro to actually generate the data, but the last step is to post them to the appropriate Confluence pages.

I've done some Googling and have gotten some tangential answers, but nothing quite on the mark. My guess is that it's not possible, but I am hoping to get something more definitive.